# FileSystemResource: how to set relative path

Tags: java, spring, resources, filesystems

I have project structure like this:

[image]

and following controller:

```
@RestController
public class StubController {

    @GetMapping("/stub_mapping_template")
    public FileSystemResource getMappingTemplate() {
        return new FileSystemResource("/stub/mapping_template.csv");
    }
}
```

but when I open in browser

```
localhost:8080/stub_mapping_template
```

nothing downloads.

in debug I tried to type:

```
new FileSystemResource("/stub/mapping_template.csv").exists()
```

and it returns `false`.

I tried to write:

```
new FileSystemResource("stub/mapping_template.csv").exists()
```

but result the same

Comment: hello, in a sevlet, you need to use getServletContext() to find the root of your project, exemple: Paths.get(getServletContext().getRealPath("web-inf/myfile");

Comment: It is **not** a file system resource. At runtime, mapping_template.csv is not on the file system. It's inside your deployed jar file, loadable by the classloader.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `FileSystemResource` use `ClassPathResource`

```
 @GetMapping("/stub_mapping_template")
    public FileSystemResource getMappingTemplate(HttpServletResponse response) {
      ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("/stub/mapping_template.csv");
      File file = classPathResource.getFile();

      InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

      response.setContentType(....);
      response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());
      response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
      FileCopyUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
      response.flushBuffer();
}
```

Comment: It is working, but browser render my csv file and not download it. How can I download this file?

Comment: to download you nede to return a stream in response(`HttpServletResponse`)

Comment: can you modify my example?

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to stick with FileSystemResource, you could do this:

```
 new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/stub/mapping_template.csv");
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhapsly FileSystemResource takes full url of your file. One of the technique is, you copy the path from "My Computer" on your pc. And keep deleting from start  of the url