# unable to download the static xml file using spring Rest Controller

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest

Here is my code snippet when i test it from postman, getting the file content but i am expecting file to be downloaded as opening window .

```
@Override
  public ResponseEntity<?> downloadXmlFile() {
    try {
       String FILE_PATH =new ClassPathResource(ApplicationConstants.my_xml).getFile().getPath();
       File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
       InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
         HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData(file.getName(),file.getName());
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
         return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(resource,headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error("Unexpected Exception occurred while serving the request" + e.getMessage());
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(new BaseResponse(AccredoStatusCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
    }
  }
```

Why I am getting file content instead of xml file to be downloaded?

Comment: checout the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47967331/filesystemresource-how-to-set-relative-path/47967366#47967366

Comment: here i am not using HttpserveletResponse class

Comment: you can use it. it doesn't change any of your existing functionality

Comment: you can also add the `ContentDisposition` to the httpHeaders. In spring 5 in class `org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders` you have the method `setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition contentDisposition)`. In Spring 4 you can user the `set` method. You may do something like this `httpHeaders.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());`

Comment: i used httpHeaders.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName()); in my code , but still xml content only retrieved in response .not working as expected.

Comment: when i run this in chrome browser , file is getting downloaded , but if running in postman , only xml content is displayed in response body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below , it is working for me.

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getFile(@PathVariable String fileName) {
        try {

            String filePath = new ClassPathResource(fileName+".xml").getFile().getPath();
            File file = new File(filePath);
            InputStream xmlFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
            headers.add("Expires", "0");
            /*headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
            String filename = fileName+".xml";
            headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
            headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");*/
            return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers)
                    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                    .body(new InputStreamResource(xmlFileInputStream));
        }
```